# Insert NaN if key is missing in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have two dictionaries

```
dict = {a:'', b:'', c:'', d:''}
ship_list = {a:'1', c:'2'}
```

for the missing keys, I expect `ship_list` shows `NaN`
like:

```
new_list = {a:'1', b:'NaN', c:'2', d:'NaN'}
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be accomplished simply using the `dict.get()` function.  [Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

#### Example:

```
empty = {'a':'', 'b':'', 'c':'', 'd':''}
filled = {'a':'1', 'c':'2'}

result = {k: filled.get(k, 'NaN') for k in empty}
```

#### Output:

```
{'a': '1', 'b': 'NaN', 'c': '2', 'd': 'NaN'}
```

#### Notes:

If you'd prefer the 'proper' `nan` value, which is a `float` data type and can be used in `None` and `isnull()`-like validation, replace the `'NaN'` with `float('nan')`.

Comment: Perfectly solve my problem. Thank you kindly for your help!